# Sunrise-commander fails to launch, cannot split window

Tags: sunrise-commander

Sunrise commander used to work fine. At some stage, and I am unaware when it happened, Sunrise now fails to launch. The error message I get is `Window #<window 3 on init.el> too small for splitting`.  I have also tried setting up these: `(split-height-threshold 5) (split-width-threshold 5)`, unfortunately this does not work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Inasmuch as the library https://github.com/escherdragon/sunrise-commander works correctly out of the box without any user configuration whatsoever, I suggest that you recursively bisect your user-configurations by commenting stuff out until you find the offending code that is breaking the functionality of `sunrise-commander`.  In addition, please read the doc-strings for `split-height-threshold` and `split-width-threshold` -- the values should probably never be 5.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to narrow down what was causing the problem. I hacked Sunrise's code instead. If you suffer from a similar problem then follow my solution(hacky) solution:

Edit sunrise-commander.el, roughly on line 1370 there is a line that looks like this:

`(split-window (selected-window) sr-panes-height)`

Change it to:

`(split-window (selected-window))`

Now preferably run `M-x byte-compile-file` and select sunrise-commander.el to compile it and thus making it faster.